# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when removing from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying simulate calls where the callers are put into a fifo linked list when no channels are available. Callers leave the queue if they run out of patience. I'm trying to write a remove function so I can remove callers from the queue when their patience is up. This is the function I wrote:

```
    void fifoqueue_remove(Fifoqueue_Ptr queue_ptr, void * this_call)
{
    Queue_Container_Ptr temp = queue_ptr->front_ptr; //make position head
    Queue_Container_Ptr prev = NULL;
    if (temp != NULL && temp->content_ptr == this_call){ //head is this this_call
        queue_ptr->front_ptr = temp->next_ptr; //make head the next call
        free((char*) temp); //delete head
        return;
    }
    while (temp != NULL && temp->content_ptr != this_call){
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next_ptr;
    }
    if (temp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    prev->next_ptr = temp->next_ptr; //found it! unlink temp from queue
    free((char*) temp);
}
```

However, when I run the simulation, the get function raises an Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) error. This function is part of the simulation library that's given to us and works perfectly fine when the remove function that I wrote is not called. The get function from the simulation library:

```
    void *
fifoqueue_get(Fifoqueue_Ptr queue_ptr)
{
  Queue_Container_Ptr removed_container_ptr;
  void* content_ptr;

  if (queue_ptr->size > 0) {
    removed_container_ptr = queue_ptr->front_ptr;
    queue_ptr->front_ptr = removed_container_ptr->next_ptr;
    content_ptr = removed_container_ptr->content_ptr;
    free((char*) removed_container_ptr);

    if(queue_ptr->size == 1) queue_ptr->back_ptr = NULL;
    queue_ptr->size--;
  }
  else {
    content_ptr = NULL;
  }
  return content_ptr;
}
```

Is my remove function somehow causing this issue? If not, what exactly is raising this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. At a minimum get the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Can also examine the program flow and variable values looking for anything that is incorrect.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)` This address (0x8) is too small to be a valid address. At the same time, it's not 0x0, so that means that somewhere you're using a NULL pointer as a pointer to a structure, and accessing an element inside that structure at position 8.

Comment: `queue_ptr->size--` Seems you are missing at least that in your remove function.